# Dynamic columns from a LEFT JOIN in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot-table, cross-apply

I have a problem and I hope you can guide me, I have 3 tables in sql server with the following characteristics:

Table **Invoice**

```
ID         Folio
------------------
1          101010
2          202020
```

Table **Additional**

```
ID           Name
--------------------------
1            Order Number
2            Branch
```

Table **AdditionalInvoice**:

```
ID_INVOICE           ID_ADDITIONAL          VALUE
------------------------------------------------------------
1                    1                      1234/1
1                    2                      NORTH
2                    1                      5678/9
2                    2                      SOUTH
```

The table 3 depends on table 1 and 2 and the ratio is one to many, I look for the following result:

Query results

```
ID          Folio          Order Number          Branch
------------------------------------------------------------
1           101010         1234/1                NORTH
2           202020         5678/9                SOUTH
```

Investigating I can use **PIVOT** or **CROSS APPLY**, but I find myself a little lost :( or someone who has another solution to the problem of dynamic columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this can be done with `PIVOT` and/or `CROSS APPLY`, I would just use conditional aggregation, which is an efficient and cross-database solution:

```
select
    i.id,
    i.folio,
    max(case when a.name = 'Order Number' then ai.value end) OrderNumber,
    max(case when a.name = 'Branch' then ai.value end) Branch
from Invoice i
inner join AdditionalInvoice ai on ai.id_invoice = i.id
inner join Additional a on a.id = ai.id_additional
group by i.id, i.folio
```

Note: rereading your question I notice a mention of *dynamic* columns at the end.

Please note that the above query (or any other pure-sql solution, `PIVOT` and `CROSS APPLY` included) only works for a *fixed* set of columns. This is because a pure SQL query can only returned a pre-defined, fixed set of columns. If you want a dynamic solution, then you need *dynamic SQL* (that is: prepare a query string, then execute it).

On the other hand, the above statement can easily be extended to handle more values from the `additional` table, by adding `max(case when ... then ... end)` expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response my friend, and in terms of impact in consultation times, which is the best option PIVOT, CROSS APPLY or the solution you mention?

Comment: @Edeveloper: I would not expect a real performance difference between the different options. Conditional aggregation *might* perform marginally better, but this should be assessed through tests againts your real data.

Comment: excellent friend, you can solve the problem with your solution, I really appreciate your help.